# What is a RESTful way to GET specific resources depending on more than one parameter?

Tags: rest, http, get, api-design, restful-url

I'm in a situation where the server has some items that are identified by two keys: type and size. Clients don't know the items ID.

Clients should be able to perform a request to get a list of the items they want. e.g.:

"Give me the circle 40, the circle 30 and the square 40".

That's easy with a json body, but we must use a GET request. Given the problem this is not useful at all: `/ids=1,2,3`.

Should we make a:

- Bizarre convention that clients should send `type_size`?
- Still bizarre convention that clients should send `type=size1,size2`
- GET request for every type?
- POST request to act as a GET?
- POST request that generates an ID to perform a subsequent GET
  request?

Comment: It's pretty common for 'collection endpoints' in REST apis to have a set of filters in the query string. Comma-separated values seems pretty reasonable!

Answer (score 0):

How would you do this with an HTML web page?

You'd probably have a web page with a form, the form would have input controls so that the client can list the items they want.  When the are finished filling in the form, the submit it.

At that point, the browser uses the data collected by the input controls to create an application/x-www-form-urlencoded document, and (because the method on the form is GET), use that document as the query part of the request uri.

```
GET /items?circle=30&circle=40&square=40
```

More generally, we can provide to the client a [URI template](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6570) that describes how information should be encoded into the URI.

But as far as HTTP is concerned: as long as the URI conforms to the production rules described by RFC 3986, it can be anything you want.  As long as the client understands how to encode the information, and the server knows to decode the information the same way, you can do what you like.